# Can you tell if a subfactor is finite depth by the growth rate of the standard invariant?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, subfactors

Let $N\subset M$ be a finite index inclusion of $II_1$ factors. To the inclusion we associate the tower of higher relative commutants

$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \mathbb{C} = N'\cap N & \subset & N'\cap M & \subset & N'\cap M_1 & \subset & \cdots  \\
                       &         & \cup     &         & \cup       &         &         \\
                       &  &\mathbb{C} = M'\cap M & \subset & M'\cap M_1 & \subset & \cdots
\end{array} $

Where $M_1$ denotes the basic construction associated to $N\subset M$. We say that this inclusion is $\textit{finite depth}$ if the Bratteli diagram  associated the the inclusion of the higher relative commutants has finite width (ie.  The number of simple factors in the commutants is bounded).

My question is:

Is it possible to determine if a subfactor is finite depth by the growth rate of the dimension of $N'\cap M_k$? I know that this is bounded above by the index. If it attains this bound does that imply finite depth?

Comment: If it attains this bound, the index is a rational number.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "it attains" ? Do you mean "it converges" or do you mean $\exists k$ such that $dim(N'\cap M_{k+1})/dim(N'\cap M_{k})=[M:N]$. In the second case the index is rational.

Comment: I meant it attains as in there exists a $k$. So this implies rational index? Does it always converge?

Comment: As you see, the index is rational by definitionn because  $dim(N' \cap M_{k+1} )/dim(N' \cap M_{k} )$ is a rational number. Next, in general it converges to the square of the norm of the principal graph, which is the index if the graph is finite, otherwise it's $\le$ the index. For example, there is a $A_{\infty}$-subfactor for every index beyond $4$, but $\Vert A_{\infty} \Vert^{2} = 4$